# C# while loop not functioning

Tags: c#, while-loop

I am trying to build a stimulate income tax calculator. The progress I am wanting to make is :

1. print out a message of "What is your total income :" to ask user to input their income in positive numeric number.
2. to read their inputs
3. make a loop: if the user put in strings, print "Enter your income as a whole-dollar numeric number",and go back to step 1. If the user put in negative number, print "Your income cannot be negative",and go back to step 1.

4.if the user has successfully enter the positve numeric number, process to step 5.

5. print out a message "How many children do you have?"
6. read the user's input.
7. make a loop: if the user types in strings, print "You must enter a valid number", and go back to step 5. If the user types in negative number, print "You must enter a positive number", and go back to step 5.
8. if the user successfully enter the postive numeric number, process to step 9.
9. put the income and children's figure in the tax calculation formula. if the totalTax <= 0, print "You owe no tax". if the total Tax > 0, print "you have to pay [tax amount] tax". END

I have tried to use the code bellow, but it doesn't work at all.

```
//Record user's income into double list "income"
double i;

//Record user's number of children into double list "kid"
double k;


//if...elif statement to calculate the toatal tax of the user
bool incomeOK = false;
bool kidOK = false;

do
{
    Console.Write("What is your total income : ");
    incomeOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);

    if (!incomeOK || i < 0)
    {
        if (!incomeOK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your income as a whole-dollar numeric figure.");
        }
        else if (i < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your income cannot be negative.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");
        kidOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k);

        while (!kidOK || k < 0)
        {
            Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");
            kidOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k);

            if (kidOK && k >= 0)
            {
                //Calculate the total payable tax of the user
                double totalTax = (i - 10000 - (k * 2000)) * 0.02;

                if (totalTax <= 10000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You owe no tax.");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You owe a total of $ " + totalTax + " tax.");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            if (!kidOK || k < 0)
            {
                if (!kidOK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must enter a valid number.");
                }
                else if (k < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must enter a positive number.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
while (!incomeOK || !kidOK);
```

but the OUTPUT:

> What is your total income : sfd
> Enter your income as a whole-dollar numeric figure.
>
> Press any key to continue...

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: Same here - what do you expect to happen for an input value of `sdf`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, too. Maybe there is a problem with the way your console behaves. If your console sends the return key two times instead of one time, ReadLine is executed twice. Try to set a breakpoint at the line "incomeOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);" and use the debugger.

Comment: i and k are bad for double.  And why are you using double for income?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split it up into sections.

First: *Get positive number*

```
double i;
double k;

Console.Write("What is your total income : ");

while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i) || i < 0)
{
    if (i < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your income cannot be negative.");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your income as a whole-dollar numeric figure.");
    }
}
```

Second: *Get number of children*

```
Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");

while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k) || k < 0)
{
    if (k < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a positive number.");
    }
    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a valid number.");
    }
}
```

Third: *Calculate*

```
double totalTax = (i - 10000 - (k * 2000)) * 0.02;

if (totalTax <= 10000)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You owe no tax.");
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("You owe a total of $ " + totalTax + " tax.");
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n Hit Enter to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Whenever you get a wrong input, the while loop forces you to stay inside. When you get out, you can be sure the input is correct.

PS: I would use `int` for number of children, because it **doesn't make any sense** that you would have **2.3** children.

Comment: You are right that splitting it up into sections is a good approach, but it is not exactly an answer to the question.

Comment: agree.. answer is not relevant to the question

Comment: Why not, the asker over complicated it, and is not sure why it's not working, or how it supposed to. This is simple, and can be easily modified, and understood.

Comment: Thank you so much mate! That works for me! Just have to tune a bit to put the Console.WriteLine() in the first and second section's if...else statement. So that the text won't be mixing into one line.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you aren't looping when it successfully parses but is a negative number.

Since your two loops are basically independent of each other, I wouldn't wrap them together in a loop (unless you intend on asking multiple times, but then that's simply another loop to repeat outside). Keep it simple and its easier to see the error. I changed it to this:

```
do
{
    Console.Write("What is your total income : ");
    incomeOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);

    if (!incomeOK) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your income as a whole-dollar numeric figure.");
        continue;
    }

    if (i < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your income cannot be negative.");
        incomeOK = false; // You need to manually set this to false to indicate it is not ok for it to loop.
    }
} while (!incomeOk)

do
{
    Console.Write("How many children do you have: ");
    kidOK = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out k);

    if (!kidOK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a valid number.");
        continue;
    }

    if(k < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a positive number.");
        kidOK = false; // Same deal as before
        continue;
    }

    /// ... Your calculations
} while (!kidOK);
```

The code is now in two loops, your inputs for income, and inputs for children. Also, there's really no need to check if it's (!incomeOK || i < 0) first. If it's not ok, you output your message and loop. If it's negative, output your message, and make sure it loops. Otherwise just proceed with normal.

Comment: Oh, well the person above beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you Bro for trying to help me out!